# Material Design Ripple Event

Tags: android, rippledrawable

For Android , I need to implement animated ripple effect when i touch on any element/view. How do i achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Android Documentation :

> Drawable that shows a ripple effect in response to state changes. The anchoring position of the ripple for a given state may be specified by calling setHotspot(float, float) with the corresponding state attribute identifier.

The effect is drawn with center specified with `setHotspot()` method

Answer (score 1):

The ripple is centered on the drawable's hotspot, which is set when the button gets touched. Check out [Drawable.setHotspot(float x, float y)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setHotspot(float,%20float)).